# How do I store and retrieve elements for ElementSelectField? Getting error "Call to a member function getUiLabel() on array"

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, field

I have a field that allows a user to select multiple products and save them to the database for a plugin, but when I try to retrieve these values and have them selected in my form I get the error

> Call to a member function getUiLabel() on array

Here is my field

```
{{ forms.elementSelectField({
    label: "Products Allowed",
    instructions: "Leave blank if this voucher has no product limits",
    id: 'products',
    name: 'products',
    elementType: productElementType,
    selectionLabel: "Add Products"),
    elements: (products is defined and products ? [products])
}) }}
```

The first question is, how do I store these values? Do I store it as it comes back? In an array, or do I encode that array to JSON? I've done both and both ways give the same error at retrieval.

Here is my retrieval code

```
$products = JSON::decode($variables['voucher']->products);


$variables['products'] = [];
foreach($products as $productId)
{
    $product = Commerce::getInstance()->getProducts()->getProductById($productId);
    ArrayHelper::append($variables['products'], $product);
}
```

As mentioned before, I've also just tried saving the products array without encoding to JSON and applying the saved results directing to `$variables['products']` with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out to an extent, I'm not sure why this works and I have a feeling it will break eventually, but here is my solution. Please let me know if there is a better one out there or something that is standard practice.

```
{{ forms.elementSelectField({
        label: "Products Allowed"|t('business-to-business'),
        instructions: "Leave blank if this voucher has no product limits",
        id: 'products',
        name: 'products',
        elementType: productElementType,
        selectionLabel: "Add Products"|t('business-to-business'),
        elements: (products is defined and products ? [products][0])
}) }}
```